# Why doesn't this interface implementation work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I seem to be having a basic syntax problem with an interface implementation.  Basically I have this:

```
    public interface IMarkerInterface
    {       
    }

    public class ConcreteObject : IMarkerInterface
    {
    }

    public interface IDoStuffInterface
    {
        void DoStuff(IMarkerInterface obj);

        // also doesn't work
        // void DoStuff<T>(T obj) where T : IMarkerInterface;
    }

    public class ConcreteDoStuff : IDoStuffInterface
    {
        public void DoStuff(ConcreteObject c)
        {

        }
    }
```

To my mind, `ConcreteObject` implements `IMarkerInterface`, so therefore `ConcreteDoStuff.DoStuff()` should implement `IDoStuffInterface`.

But I get a compilation error `"Error ConcreteDoStuff does not implement interface IDoStuffInterface.DoStuff()"`

How come?

Comment: Is DoStuff public in IDoStuffInterface?  That is not how you showed it in this example

Comment: @Hogan Isn't everything in an interface public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implemented methods need to have the exact same signature as the interface.  While all 'ConcreteObject' objects are of type 'IMarkerInterface', not all 'IMarkerInterfaces' will be 'ConcreteObject'.  Thus the two signatures are not equivalent.  Interfaces must be able to guarantee the CLR that any object of that type has a valid method implemented.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly the same? Is there no room for (the right kinds of) variance? I honestly don't know.

Comment: @jtimperley - Thank you.  Now that you put it that way, I feel a little foolish =)

Answer (score 4):

If I give you any object implementing `IDoStuffInterface`, then you expect to be able to call a method `DoStuff` on it with as its argument *any object* that implements `IMarkerInterface`, right? However, if what you want would be possible, then you could *somehow* (invisible to you as user of the interface) only call `DoStuff` with a `ConcreteObject`, but *not* any other object implementing `IMarkerInterface`. Therefore, what you want is not really possible (nor desired, as it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

However, what you want can be done writing an [*explicit interface member implementation*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx) that implements the interface's `DoStuff(IMarkerInterface)` method, while providing a normal method `DoStuff(ConcreteObject)` implementation next to it. Any user of the interface will only see and be able to call the `DoStuff(IMarkerInterface)` method, but any user of `ConcreteDoStuff` will only directly be able to call the `DoStuff(ConcreteObject)` method. If the user wants to call the interface method anyway, the object *must* be cast to `IDoStuffInterface` first.

```
public class ConcreteDoStuff : IDoStuffInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation:
    // This method is not directly visible as a member of the class.
    void IDoStuffInterface.DoStuff(IMarkerInterface obj)
    {
        // Do something with 'obj', or throw an exception when
        // it has the wrong type. Delegate the call to the
        // other DoStuff method if you wish.
    }

    // Normal method, technically not related to the interface method:
    public void DoStuff(ConcreteObject c)
    {
        // Do your thing.
    }
}
```

---

*Edit:*

#### Interesting workaround! Would you consider this to be common practice? Or is the workaround more of a "hack" to be avoided?

The technique of explicitly implementing an interface is well known, well understood and quite common. It is not considered to be a *hack*, and does not have to be avoided. It is even required in the rare case that a class implements two interfaces that both define a member with the same name, but you want to give them different behaviors.

However, in all cases where you limit the allowed input values or actions, you violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP). In my example, you would limit the `IMarkerInterface obj` parameter to `ConcreteObject` objects. Other examples include: a [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) that throws an exception when a `null` object is added; an [`IComparable.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) implementation that throws an error when the argument has the wrong type; or a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) that throws an exception when calling its `Add` method.

While the LSP should not be violated (so the code becomes more (re)usable and testable), it *is* violated quite often, even in the .NET Framework itself. Not violating it in some cases may be cumbersome, result in hard-to-read code, or may even be impossible (e.g. due to restrictions of the classes and interfaces of the .NET Framework).

As I said, the same 'workaround' is applied to implementations of `IComparable`. For example, to implement a class that may only be compared to other objects of the same type:

```
public class BeanBag : IComparable, IComparable<BeanBag>
{
    private int beanCount;

    // Explicit interface member implementation:
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is BeanBag))
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type!");
        // Calls the normal CompareTo() method.
        return CompareTo((BeanBag)other);
    }

    // Normal CompareTo method:
    public int CompareTo(BeanBag other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return this.beanCount.CompareTo(other.beanCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround!  Would you consider this to be common practice?  Or is the workaround more of a "hack" to be avoided?

Comment: @anon - I added an answer to your question to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementing class, `ConcreteDoStuff`, is trying to change the contract. Unilaterally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implemet method with matching signature:

```
public class ConcreteDoStuff : IDoStuffInterface
{
    public void DoStuff(IMarkerInterface c) // not ConcreteObject c
    {

    }
}
```

Note you still can call ConcreteDoStuff.DoStuff with an instance of ConcreteObject :

```
 var concrete = new ConcreteObject()
 new ConcreteDoStuff().DoStuff(concrete);
```

You can also do this (explicit implementation of interface) if it works better for you:

```
public class ConcreteDoStuff : IDoStuffInterface
{
    public void DoStuff(ConcreteObject c)
    {

    }

    void IDoStuffInterface.DoStuff(IMarkerInterface c)
    {
       // some implementation preferably related to
       // DoStuff(ConcreteObject) i.e.: 
       DoStuff(c as ConcreteObject); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By only accepting `ConcreteObject` in your implementation of `ConcreteDoStuff.DoStuff()` you have limited the type of arguments that can be passed in.

If you were to create another class that also implemented the `IMarkerInterface`:

```
public class ConcreteObject2 : IMarkerInterface
{
}
```

It should be able to be passed in to any `DoStuff()` implementation, but `ConcreteObject2` is not a `ConcreteObject` by definition, therefore the contract will bi violated, as the other answers have indicated.

Answer (score 1):

You're best off using a generic interface:

```
public interface IMarkerInterface
{       
}

public class ConcreteObject : IMarkerInterface
{
}

public interface IDoStuffInterface<T>
{
    void DoStuff(T obj);
}

public class ConcreteDoStuff : IDoStuffInterface<ConcreteObject>
{
    public void DoStuff(ConcreteObject c)
    {

    }
}
```